# How to verify index_name works in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

How can you verify if index_name property works correctly in elasticsearch. i.e. how to verify if elasticsearch internally stores field key using index_name.

Below is my mapping.

```
POST testalias
{
   "mappings": {
      "test": {
         "properties": {
            "keywords" : { "type" : "string", "index_name": "kd" }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I store data as below

```
POST testalias/test/
{
    "keywords": "mykey123"
}
```

When I lookup http://localhost:9200/testalias/_search?q=*&pretty I get the response with

```
"_source":{
    "keywords": "mykey123"
}
```

So the response shows the field name "keywords", but how can I confirm internally es stores it as "kd". This is important because my field names are very long and I want to use index_name to save disk space. My business reason is based on this post [cost of keys in JSON document database (mongodb, elasticsearch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492785/cost-of-keys-in-json-document-database-mongodb-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

- You can try to search with query dsl and you use kd field : (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)
- You can check the mapping. If you have kd field and keywords field, it's wrong. Try to index with "kd" field and not "keywords".